# Regex only allow dash in between characters

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, validation

I have this regex `^[A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå\ \-]{2,50}$` for validating names. How can I make it allow only one "-". I want it to accept names like this:

```
Janet Smith-Johnson
Mary-Ann Johnson
Sara Mary John-Smith
Sara Johnson
Sara Mary Johnson
```

But it can't allow names that starts with `-` and ends with `-`. Like:

```
-Janet Mary
Mary-
```

Comment: This is definitely possible, but I think having a split in the regex means you can't also enforce the maximum length at the same time (that's easy enough to do as a separate check though)

Comment: no, no space at the start or end @anubhava

Comment: I stand corrected, you *can* enforce the length with positive lookahead!

Comment: @WiktorStribizew why did you delete your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=.{2,50}$)(?!(?:.*-){2})[A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]+(?:[- ][A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regexr.com/6gfse).

If you are using the regex in C# or with `u` flag in JavaScript that supports ECMAScript 2018+ standard, you can also match any Unicode letter with `\p{L}`:

```
^(?=.{2,50}$)(?!(?:.*-){2})\p{L}+(?:[- ]\p{L}+)*$
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{2,50}$)` - two to fifty chars in the string allowed
- `(?!(?:.*-){2})` (or `(?!(?:[^-]*-){2})` in the real code is more efficient) - no two hyphens are allowed
- `[A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]+` - one or more letters from the set (`\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter)
- `(?:[- ][A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]+)*` - zero or more sequences of either space or `-` and then one or more letters
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

You can match your character class without spaces, then optionally repeat a space and again use the character class without spaces.

Then optionally match `-` and the same mechanism again.

```
^(?=.{2,50}$)[A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]+(?: [A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]+)*(?:-[A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]+(?: [A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]+)*)?$
```

The pattern in parts matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.{2,50}$)` Assert 2 - 50 characters
- `[A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]+` Match what is listed in the character class without a space
- `(?: [A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]+)*` Optionally repeat the character class preceded by a space
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole

  - `-[A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]+` Match what is listed in the character class without a space
  - `(?: [A-ZÆØÅa-zæøå]+)*` Optionally repeat the character class preceded by a space
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nMyfWN/1)